# Techwell tw6805a driver for ubuntu 14.04 LTS running 3.13.0-55-generic kernel

Tags: drivers, kernel

I am using ubuntu server 14.04 LTS and have a 16 channel DVR card installed, unfortunately it is a no-name-brand, however I have identified 8 techwell tw8605a chips on the board.

I followed the instructions on

[this](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1609560) page and have the same issue when it comes to the "make" step. On various of the forum pages I have followed suggestions to resolve the issue but still I get the same error as below:

```
manager@SecSrv:~/module$ sudo make
[sudo] password for manager:
make -C /lib/modules/3.13.0-55-generic/build M= modules
make[1]: Entering directory `/usr/src/linux-headers-3.13.0-55-generic'
make[2]: *** No rule to make target `/usr/src/linux-headers-3.13.0-55-generic/arch/x86/syscalls/syscall_32.tbl', needed by `arch/x86/syscalls/../include/generated/uapi/asm/unistd_32.h'.  Stop.
make[1]: *** [archheaders] Error 2
make[1]: Leaving directory `/usr/src/linux-headers-3.13.0-55-generic'
make: *** [all] Error 2
manager@SecSrv:~/module$
```

I have checked the kernel version match as seen on one of the forum pages.

I really need to know if these drivers will work or if I am wasting every bodies time.

Much appreciate any help